# Create JSON with correct key-value strings to be parsed

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I have a requirement to reproduce a json, basically to run some tests on my code that is used to parse similar json in real-time.

This is my code snippet, event is generated from s3 PUT notification i.e. published to SQS from SNS listener -

```
event_body = json.loads(event["Records"][0]["body"])
event_body_msg = json.loads(event_body['Message'])
event_body_dict = event_body_msg['Records'][0]
s3_buck = event_body_dict['s3']['bucket']['name']
```

I want my json to contain the hierarchical structure that would be parsed by this code (as my test is written on the value of s3_buck). Here is the json I came up with -

> {
>       "Records": [
>           {
>               "messageId": "a6665910-ab5a-46c3-baaf-6086c0c90511",
>               "receiptHandle": "AQEBscBCR7DwSLqd5SXvEAX+8NUImpMPNmJ9hSD03HgWHhPnNZoIIqHkqI8lvwGMLjhX2R1ogPfo09z8EHcI7Nuh851vi4cIPBngMbIS6yw/rBtG115vSUyfN8i1yKM6Oz7iSJ2kIJCGmWRF2Rhsc8dH31zcyZKbVz/SzCOK8S/E9SdFHkPi2iNm4tr4PgrI+ZrvtYUicOuZQAJ8++hYo0rB43YCZKSZWMV1LG4iz2+OKVO08qZv3WyJ3pUegW4LXNp1xAf2abep44lYgWqqDWyWRlnpKayagqaTSaqR/OzNM3Iky9MnXqVz3g7CRBO28h2noUy4T6cW6HmlZ+xe3TWHOToJeWqiRnsY1HYuZxGscRpDUXIq5V7pZPhkLU2XbdQg",
>               "body": "{\"Message\": {\"Records\": [{\"s3\": {\"bucket\": {\"name\": \"demo-bucket-name\",\"arn\":
>   \"arn:aws:s3:::demo-bucket-name\"},\"object\": {\"key\":
>   \"demo-key-prefix.json\"}}}]}}"
>           }
>           ]
>       }

I am trying to replicate aws sns notification to create a sample json that would only contain attributes for my usecase. Here is the sample event sns produces(copied from the lambda console) - https://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IUAE3.  I am only picking attributes that I need like s3 bucket_name or arn etc.

However, the problem here is that I run into errors where I run event["Records"][0]["body"], with the error message -

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/**init**.py",
>   line 354, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py",
>   line 342, in decode
>       raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end) json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 251 (char 250)

I tried enclosing the json string inside "body" key using r""" but no luck. Wondering what's the right format to create the json.

Answer (score 1):

`body` is not valid as a JSON string. It contains 2 records without `[` and `,`.

Let's print your body string then validate with https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Ah..fixed that(in the question as well), now it succeeds to json.loads() and create event_body. However, the content inside with "Records" is still identified as dictionary (and hence loads() fails). I tried adding quotes to the "Records" dict but it then fails at the loads() to create event_body with the error message - "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 16 (char 15)".

Comment: I think this is other question. But I still paste code here. `print(json.loads(event["Records"][0]["body"])["Message"]["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"])`

Comment: You should not update question by remove old messages. Thanks